# how to mail script output in table format

Tags: linux, bash, shell, email

I have the script output like below.

Current result:

```
Filename Destname rowcount bytesize
file1 default 1488 2248
file2 default 123 657
file3 default 123 456
file4 default 567 124
```

Actual result to be like below (if possible with borders):

```
Filename  Destname  rowcount  bytesize
file1     default   1488      2248
file2     default   123       657
file3     default   123       456
file4     default   567       124
```

I need to mail above content in same format.

Comment: This (to my eyes) is already a table with proper indentation.

Comment: What specific table format do you have in mind? For example, are you looking to put | vertical | lines | in | between | each | column?

Comment: Please be more specific and attach what you have already tried, see [ask]. Additionally, `bash` and `PowerShell` are radically differing shell languages, please be specific about which shell you're asking about.

Comment: current I am getting this content with out proper indentation. Its like a single row with out any spaces.

Comment: Do you want to convert this to a HTML page/table?

Comment: yes. its fine with HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

input="/path/to/your/file.txt"
tmpfile="/path/to/tmpfile.html"

echo 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii" ' > "$tmpfile"
awk 'BEGIN{print "<html><body><table border=1>"} {print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td>" $i"</td>";print "</tr>"} END{print "</table></body></html>"}' "$input" >> "$tmpfile"
mail -s "test" abc@xyz.com < "$tmpfile"
```

Source: http://www.unix.com/302556864-post5.html